# What inequality does the units digit of a two digit number less than $40$ satisfy if the sum of the units digit and tens digit equals $8$?

Tags: arithmetic

For a two digit number , the sum of the "units digit" and "tens digit" is $8$ and the two-digit number is less than $40$.

Denoting that the "units digit" of the two-digit number to be $x$, form an inequality and solve for $x$.

I'm not sure how to find the "tens digit" as I have problems understanding the question .
Thanks for helping ..

Comment: If a two digit number is less than $40$, then the tens digit is at least $1$ and at most $3$.

Answer (score 0):

You have two things here... let $x$ be the units digit and let $w$ be the tens digit:  you know that

$$w+x=8$$
$$10w+x<40$$

Thus

$$9w+w+x<40\Rightarrow 9w+8<40\Rightarrow 9w<32\Rightarrow w<3.6$$

So $w$ can be $1,2,3$.  That gives possibilities....

Comment: Why did u multiply w by 10? Sorry a little bit of understanding problem here ..

Comment: when you have a two digit number, like say 31, this is the same as $3\times 10+1$...

Comment: any number can be written as a sum of coefficients times powers of 10.  For example again, $123=1\cdot 10^2+2\cdot 10+3\cdot 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t$ denote the tens digit; let $x$ denote the units digit.  Since the sum of the tens digit and the units digit is $8$, 
$$t + x = 8$$
Since the two-digit number is less than $40$, $1 \leq t \leq 3$.  Since 
$$x = 8 - t$$
you can determine the possible values of $x$.